# Word for a specific crutch gait

Tags: word-choice, word-request

When looking up some medical terms regarding crutch gait, I found a plethora of resources that detail the different ways how one can properly walk on crutches.
One of this ways is the so called "Two-Point Gait". In this "mode", the patient always advances the foot with the crutch on the opposite side of the body.
Have a look at this video for a demonstration: https://youtu.be/qjukAMe3qJE?t=27

Just in case the link goes dead, let me try to illustrate it with a simple drawing (`x` foot with injury, `>` other foot, `|` crutch):

```
  |   |   |   |
x   x   x   x
  >   >   >   >
|   |   |   |
```

It does not really matter, but consider the walking direction from left to right.

Long story short, the **question** is:
Is there a special term for the walking pattern where a patient does the opposite of what is expected and basically puts foot and crutch of the same side forward at the same time?

Using the notation from above, that might look as follows:

```
|   |   |   |
x   x   x   x
  >   >   >   >
  |   |   |   |
```

I have heard some people (physiotherapists) refer to this as "Passgang" in German. According to my research, the direct translation is *amble*<sup>1,2</sup>, but the term seems to be primarily used for horses<sup>3</sup> (or other animals with four legs) or as a term to describe relaxed walking<sup>3,4,5</sup>.

*Edit:*

Prior to asking this question, I studied the following resources:

- https://www.physio-pedia.com/Crutches
- https://walkeasy.com/explore/crutch-gaits.php
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElZkPye4WtA / https://www.registerednursern.com/crutches-nursing-nclex-review/

@MichaelHarvey, added https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-to-walk-safely-with-crutches-2696295 to the list. Thanks for that!

All these sites describe how to use crutches in various modes, but none of them matches what I'm looking for. My best guess would be, that what I'm looking for is an error on the patient's side, i.e. you would not want the patient to walk like this.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/Passgang.html
<sup>2</sup> https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/passgang
<sup>3</sup> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amble
<sup>4</sup> https://www.lexico.com/definition/amble
<sup>5</sup> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amble

Comment: If there is, it will be specialist medical jargon.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too specialised.

Comment: Do we have a Medical SE or something similar? You can try your luck there.

Comment: As @MichaelHarvey says, there are several web pages that describe the various types of crutch gates. It would be acceptable on medical sciences, but might get downvoted for lack of prior research.

Comment: The German term _passgang_ refers to a gait of horses where the legs on the same side of the body move together, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passgang for an explanation and some rather lovely film examples. JamesK has given you the English equivlents

Comment: Off topic, but amusing: DeepL had a go at _Passgang_ and turned it into _passport aisle_ ;-) Good effort, DeepL!

Comment: Nothing to do with crutches really has any word other than "gait" and they are all described using terms like two-point and three-point. Ergo, the likelihood there is a term for not using them correctly is close to nil. Not interested. I just want you to clarify your question, that's all. Also, ambling cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild googling using different combinations of words suggested in the comments, the [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/285963/136879) by [@JamesK](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/24231/james-k), together with "arm"/"leg"/"same side", and so on surfaced some references to *namba (or nanba) walking*, seemingly originating from Japanese culture, and also found in martial arts ([demonstration at a TEDx talk](https://youtu.be/-BLhcIRxhck)). But I don't expect this term to be used in medicine.

There also seems to be scientific literature about it (e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266794730_AN_ENERGY-EFFICIENT_LOCOMOTION_SAMURAI-INSPIRED_NAMBA_WALKING), though I cannot judge its reliability. The term *ipsilateral movement* was used there in the description of Figure 1. Obviously, crutches are not a topic in this paper, but at least from my non-medical perspective, something like *ipsilateral crutch gait* could work.

Answer (score 3):

There are no non-medical terms for crutch gaits (that I, as a non-specialist, am aware of).  For general four-leg gaits, your first is "trotting" and the second is "pacing.  These apply particularly to horses, where some horses trot (moving diagonal legs at the same time) and some pace (moving both left legs at the same time, then both right legs).

An amble (in animal gaits) is a slower pace in which the animal moves Back-left, front-left, back-right, front-right. It is more stable, as there are always three points of contact with the ground.

It would be natural for the terms for four-legged animal locomotion to transfer to humans, when we use our arms with crutches as extra legs.

Comment: I find your arguments plausible. If that's what one would call it in English, I'm perfectly fine with it. I'm just want to wait a bit to see if something else comes up.

Comment: @AlexV I do not think any speaker without a detailed knowledge of equestrianism would have any idea what these technical terms mean (pace or trot).

Comment: People can amble too. However, not with crutches. He ambled down the street.

Comment: "Pace" quite a technical term in horse riding (though I'm aware of it as part of general knowledge.  I know, for example, that camels tend to rock from side to side as they pace which makes them "ships of the desert".  Amble is quite technical. But I think any native speaker would know "trot, canter, and gallop". These aren't technical at all.

Comment: @JamesK I too would expect most native speakers to know ‘trot’, ‘canter’, and ‘gallop’ — but I don't think many would associate them with specific gaits, only with rough speeds.